# Surfingkeys browser extension has enabled, disabled, and lurk mode. How do I add a list of websites in surfingkeys to browse in the lurk mode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, regex, browser-addons, web

Lurk mode is better than disabling suringkeys altogether. For example, Gmail website has list of abundant shortcuts, but still it's better to have surfingkeys' shortcuts as yourbackup. In lurkmode you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>(or p for passing through just one action of surfingkeys) to use surfingkeys and then press Esacape to go back to lurkmode.

The readme file of github page says to add github in the surfing key lurkmode use the regex line bellow.

```
settings.lurkingPattern = /https:\/\/github\.com|.*confluence.*/i;
```

But that doesn't say what if I want to add many websites, around 10-20 maybe, to browse in lurk mode.The regex pattern in the line
`/https:\/\/github\.com|.*confluence.*/i;`
is not simple. For example if I add
`/https:\/\/meet\.jit.si|.*confluence.*/i;`
then it works for jitsi conference room. But if I add just
`/https:\/\/github\.com.*` or `/https:\/\/github\.com.`
then it may not work,(if I remember correctly). So probably the word confluence is not just a word but a keyword. IDK. I know how to add websites after websites in surfingkeys blocklist. But I want to add around 10-15 websites in surfingkeys lurk-mode list.

I have knowledge of basic regex in case that would be needed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more URLs in the alternative:

```
/https:\/\/(github\.com|meet\.jit\.si|example\.com|example\.net)|.*confluence.*/i;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks @Toto. Just for curiosity, do you know what the *confluence.*/i; part do? is the ending semicolon necessary?

Comment: @sourajghosh: `.*confluence.*` matches anything that contain the word `confluence` somewhere i the string. `/i` stand for case insensitive, it means the match is done regardless the case (i.e.: `abc` & `ABC` are considered the same). The final semicolon is mandatory or not depending on the language used. You'll find complete explanation of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/ImKHNo/1).

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation as bonus on top of giving the solution. In case I am not being to nagging, I still didn't understand the .*confluence.*/i part.
Like since I know regex I understand that .* is meant to match anything before confluence where dot(.) means any character and * means zero or more match. And the second .* part matches anything after the word 'confluence'. And /i is for case insensitive. But what's the purpose of matching confluence. And why confluence among so many other words. I tried searching the word confluence but wasn't so successful in regards to this context

Comment: @sourajghosh: Well, I don't know why they have used the word `confluence`, may be it's explained in the readme file. If you don't need this word in your regex, remove it, (i.e.: remove `|.*confluence.*`, including the pipe character).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. Well I forgot which site it was, maybe jit.si where I tried to remove that confluence part, and it didn't go well. 

But for now it suffices because since you said you are not aware of the reason behind the word confluence, I am assuming it doesn't have to do anything with regex. 
So I want to mark this question 'answered successfully' although I don't know how to do that.  IG I will find out and then will mark it answered. 

Thanks again.